# How to automatically turn off a camera stream after a set amount of time in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, video-processing

I'm trying to code a program that will detect motion and turn off the camera when there is no motion for more than 5s using OpenCV. The code does print "Motion" and captures motion for about 8-10s before turning off the camera, regardless if there was motion or not. I'm not really sure which part of the code is causing this and any help would greatly be appreciated!!

```
import cv2
import time

cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

ret1,background= cap.read()
gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(background, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray1, (21, 21), 0)
cv2.imshow('window',background)
t0 = time.time() # start time in seconds
imgCounter = 0

def getMovement (img):
    motion = None
    gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(frame2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray2, (21, 21), 0)

    frameComparison=cv2.absdiff(gray1,gray2)
    threshold = cv2.threshold(frameComparison, 25, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    threshold = cv2.dilate(threshold,None)
    countour,heirarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for i in countour:
        if cv2.contourArea(i) < 50:
            motion = False
            continue
        motion = True
    return motion



while(True):
    ret2,frame2=cap.read()
    motion = getMovement(frame2)

    cv2.imshow('window',frame2)

    cv2.waitKey(1)
    if motion:
        print("MOTION")
    else: # no motion for a bit, so the timer starts 
         t1 = time.time() # current time
         num_seconds = t1 - t0 # diff
         if num_seconds > 5: 
         # once it hits 5s, it should take a picture and turn off
            print("No motion in 5s")
            cv2.imwrite("Motion test.png", frame2)
            break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a small mistake i.e. you are not `t0` when motion is detected. So you are taking difference between current time with time at which timer initiated at the beginning while checking for no motion.

So try this inside the loop:

```
if motion:
    t0 = time.time()
    print("MOTION")
```

Comment: I just tried that now and it was exactly what I needed! I didn't think of restarting the timer. Thank you.